# Cron job, execute php script

Tags: php, scripting, cron, execute

I want to run a php script every morning, the script would send an email.

But the email I get from cron always contains an error message.

Can somebody please help?

Comment: Well, what is the error message?

Comment: What kind of server are you on? Please post some more detailed info, otherwise people will have to write book-long answers covering every possible server platform, just to discover that you're on a shared host and can't do it at all.

Comment: @Arnold, I rolled your question back to its original form. Don't be pissed off, SO is a very friendly community overall. Just provide some more detail to your question and I'm sure it will be answered. Oh and welcome to SO :)

Answer (score 12):

Yes. I'm sure someone here can.

Answer (score 2):

Post your script, crontab line and error.  You might want to try piping your script output to sendmail instead of sending mail through PHP.

Comment: Why was this downvoted? It's the only constructive reply. +1 to even it out.

Comment: Thanks Pekka.  Here's a sample from the web:
*/10 * * * * /bin/execute/this/script.sh 2>&1 | mail -s "Cronjob ouput" yourname@yourdomain.com

Comment: TFM for crontab says that if you modify the MAILTO variable you will get output to a different address, obviating the need to invoke /bin/mail.

Considering that he's getting an error, I'm going to go out on a limb and say that $PATH needs to be corrected. Again, this is noted in TFM.